# how to find sum of group and find weight in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum

I have one table for company here is the structure:

```
 +------------+--------------+-----------+--------+-----------------------------+
 | ticker     | total_shares | institute | public | sector                      |
 +------------+--------------+-----------+--------+-----------------------------+
 | 1JANATAMF  |    200000000 |     30.00 |  45.00 | Mutual Funds                |
 | 8THICB     |      5000000 |      0.00 |   0.00 | Mutual Funds                |
 | AAMRATECH  |     55369395 |     28.00 |  42.00 | IT Sector                   |
 | ABB1STMF   |    162615643 |     46.44 |  33.56 | Mutual Funds                |
 | ABBANK     |    532459152 |     54.86 |  30.01 | Bank                        |
 | ACI        |     28661768 |     37.73 |  28.23 | Pharmaceuticals & Chemicals |
 | ACIFORMULA |     45000000 |     22.77 |  11.21 | Pharmaceuticals & Chemicals |
 | ACIZCBOND  |       267170 |     60.00 |  40.00 | Corporate Bond              |
 | ACTIVEFINE |     69000000 |     20.80 |  64.42 | Pharmaceuticals & Chemicals |
 | AFCAGRO    |     50000000 |     48.11 |  21.60 | Pharmaceuticals & Chemicals |
 | AFTABAUTO  |     95732422 |     47.49 |  22.01 | Engineering                 |
 | AGNISYSL   |     51798982 |     16.33 |  70.92 | IT Sector                   |
 | AGRANINS   |     24157650 |     18.30 |  43.05 | Insurance                   |
 | AIBL1STIMF |    100000000 |     76.31 |  13.69 | Mutual Funds                |
 | AIMS1STMF  |     41450000 |      0.00 |   0.00 | Mutual Funds                |
 | AL-HAJTEX  |     12691843 |      4.19 |  71.76 | Textile                     |
 | ALARABANK  |    946958501 |     10.07 |  46.88 | Bank                        |
 +------------+--------------+-----------+--------+-----------------------------+
```

Another table for price :

```
 +------------+--------+--------+------------+
 | ticker     | open   | high   | price_date |
 +------------+--------+--------+------------+
 | AAMRATECH  |  29.80 |  30.20 | 2014-05-04 |
 | ABBANK     |  27.50 |  27.50 | 2014-05-04 |
 | ACI        | 235.00 | 244.50 | 2014-05-04 |
 | ACIFORMULA |  86.00 |  87.60 | 2014-05-04 |
 | ACTIVEFINE |  69.00 |  70.00 | 2014-05-04 |
 | BANGAS     | 509.50 | 509.50 | 2014-05-04 |
 | BANKASIA   |  18.00 |  18.40 | 2014-05-04 |
 +------------+--------+--------+------------+
```

of course data has been shorted for a purpose. now i wanted find the weighted price of open. the formula for this is

```
A = open*((total_share*(institue/100)+(total_share*(public/100))
```

them sum of A by sector like sum all ticker belongs to Mutual funds. then divide the individual ticker for example 1JANATAMF/ sum of mutual funds to find the weight.

I have used this query :

```
select c.ticker, 
p.open*(c.total_shares*(c.institute/100)+c.total_shares*(c.public/100)) as cap
from company as c
left join price as p
on p.ticker =c.ticker
where p.price_date = '2014-05-04';
```

but can't find a way to get sum by sector and find the weight.

**Edit:** 
**Output will be like** 
Ticker, **A/(sum of A with grouped by sector)** 
where, A is the formulated value according to ticker

output will be like:

```
 +------------+--------------+--------------+
 | ticker     | sum(a)       | weight       |
 +------------+--------------+--------------+
 | 1JANATAMF  |   5700000000 |    150078540 |
```

Comment: Your weight calculation is slightly confused how a ticker i.e (1JANATAMF) string value can be divisible by numeric value like sum of sector,can you clear it ?

Comment: you misunderstood the numeric result that i am getting from my above query or by A. for example 1JANATAMF's A say 50 and its belong to Mutual Fund there are many other companies in mutual fund sector like 1JANATAMF, i want sum of all A by sector then weight is calculated by this way A/sum of that sector.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the results that you want for the given data.

Comment: edited and provided clear output

Answer (score 0):

Break your query in some views, see if it was what you nedd in SQLFiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7b4cb/4/2

Comment: hi many thanks for your help, i'm almost there, but stuck ta last step can you tell me how can have sum of weight of each sectors? for example from your result i need (0.452644163162+0.133979939858+0.413375896979) summed and show the sector name no need ticker as i need the summed weight of each sector. and  can i multiply the weight with open from price table?  like this?  select  lc.sector, p.open*(cap/sum_cap) as open
from list_cap lc
join list_sum_cap lsc
on lsc.sector = lc.sector
join price as p
on lc.ticker =p.ticker; 

thanks

Comment: another question is if i create view where p.price_date = '2014-05-04' and need to change the date do i need to create view each time?